# Json sort by id which will be obtained from database

Tags: php, android, html, json

I am having a problem in JSON. I want to sort my JSON in increasing order of variable id.

This is JSON data at present

```
{"server_response":[{"id":"9","email":"test@gmail.com=","password":"test"},{"id":"5","email":"json@gmail.com","password":"json"},{"id":"14","email":"wrong@gmail.com","password":"test"},{"id":"13","email":"mail@gmail.com=","password":"mail"}]}
```

php file i am using right now is

```html
<?php

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$sql = "select * from users;";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"email"=>$row[1],"password"=>$row[2]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

But i want my output as shown below.Any changes for php file ???

```
{"server_response":[{"id":"5","email":"json@gmail.com","password":"json"},{"id":"9","email":"test@gmail.com=","password":"test"},{"id":"13","email":"mail@gmail.com=","password":"mail"},{"id":"14","email":"wrong@gmail.com","password":"test"}]}
```

Comment: Either use DESC in your query or sort on client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort in your client side but it would be better if you do it from the server side only. What you need to do is:

```
$sql = "select * from users order by id;";
```

This should work. If you want it in descending order, add the keyword: 'desc' after id (without the single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code...

```
<?php

$json = '{"server_response":[{"id":"9","email":"test@gmail.com=","password":"test"},{"id":"5","email":"json@gmail.com","password":"json"},{"id":"14","email":"wrong@gmail.com","password":"test"},{"id":"13","email":"mail@gmail.com=","password":"mail"}]}
';
$arr = json_decode($json,true); //Converts your json into array

$main = $arr['server_response']; // your array for sorting

$list = array_sort($main, 'id', SORT_ASC); //makes function call
print_r($list);  //desired result

function array_sort($array, $on, $order=SORT_ASC){

    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
?>
```